# C# How to read Multiple Pointers Value with VAMemory.dll

Tags: c#, memory

I have a base address and few pointers that I need to read the Value off them using VAMemory.dll on C#.

https://i.postimg.cc/QdfxtnbD/sdfsdfsdfdg.png

I have done it this way:

```
VAMemory vam = new VAMemory(process);
int LocalPlayer = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)0x00EE231C);
int address = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(LocalPlayer + 0x30));
address = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(address + 0x0));
address = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(address + 0x1BC));
address = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(address + 0x178));
address = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(address + 0x0));
address = address + 0x4;

int value = vam.ReadInt32((IntPtr)address);
Console.WriteLine("     value: " + value);
```

But it's not working. I have checked few solutions here on StackOverflow but still can't find a valid solution.
I can read the value very well using Cheat Engine so the pointers aren't invalid. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, you have a base address and some offsets. A pointer is offset from an address. 
You call `IntPtr.Add(address, offset)` to add an offset to each computed pointer.

```
private int GetPointerValue(Int32 baseAddress, int[] offsetArr)
{
    IntPtr pointer = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(baseAddress), offsetArr[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < offsetArr.Length; i++)
    {
        pointer = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(pointer), offsetArr[i]);
    }
    return vam.ReadInt32(pointer);
}

private Int32 baseAddress = 0xEE231C;
private var offsetArr = new int[]{ 0x30, 0x0, 0x1BC, 0x178, 0x0, 0x4 };

Console.WriteLine("     value: " + GetPointerValue(baseAddress, offsetArr));
```

Comment: Hey,
I've implemented it now there is one problem that says: 
"cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.IntPtr' " 
for this line:
var pointer = IntPtr.Add((IntPtr)vam.ReadInt32(baseAddress), offsetArr[0]);

Comment: Sorry I didn't test this. change var to IntPtr. As well as var baseAddress to Int32 baseAddress. I edited it in the code you can reference. You can take a look at how I've done this in the past at my github https://github.com/mfloob/TreeGlide/blob/master/TreeGlide/Managers/MemoryManager.cs